# How to show several docs with the same field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that have a ”CompanyId” field that can be the same for multiple documents.

I want Elasticsearch to take up to 3 documents with the same “CompanyId” and the highest score, and then rank them in the overall output by comparing them with the score of other documents.

I use collapse, but all the collapsed documents remain in inner_hits and I can't get from there either:

```
"collapse": {
  "field": "CompanyId",
  "max_concurrent_group_searches": 3"inner_hits": {
    "name": "top_hits",
    "size": 3,
    "sort": [
      {
        "_score": "desc"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```